# Measures to prevent from closing a program

Tags: c#

Say I have a simple C# monitoring program that is to be installed on some company computers, so I know what the employees are doing. The program is a single .exe file that works in the system tray. How do I prevent employees from closing this program? Is there a way to be notified when a program is closed?

Comment: Does employees know that they are being monitored?

Comment: How do we know that you are not writing a virus and the employees are in fact victims of this virus?

Comment: What about human rights?

Comment: @Shoban: Of course. I'm not looking for a way to hide the program.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: We don't, and it doesn't matter for us, as long as he doesn't tell us. [This was already discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80495/policy-regarding-questions-related-to-unethical-or-shady-practices).

Comment: Make sure users does not log in as Administrator. Run as a service, and disallow the users from stopping that service.

Comment: @khachik - Human rights and **employee rights** are two very different things. If you're using equipment provided by an employer, and your contract/workplace rules state that monitoring is permitted, then you have no rights. Human rights are irrelevant in the scenario described by the OP.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want users to close your program, run it under a different account. Normal users can't kill processes they don't own, ie that run using different accounts. Of course, this means that you can't run your program as a simple application that displays a taskbar notification. You will have to convert it to a service.

In fact, a service makes a lot more sense than a user application in this scenario. If you want to display feedback or options to the user you can still create an app that creates a taskbar icon and communicates with your service

Answer (score 4):

Set it up as a service and in the options for the service on first, second, and third failure - make it reboot the computer. Have the service `login-as` an service user with a strong password and prevent the users from running as Administrators. This should solve your problem and probably create a bit of annoyance at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

**The short answer:** No.

**The long answer:** Yes...write a rootkit which will either guard or hide your process. Otherwise the users will be able to kill the process f.e. via the Task-Manager or any other means. Same goes for any helper processes which would monitor your application.